# Accounting spaces in palindrome program

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

This is a program that accepts a string of words and checks if the words are palindromes and if it is one, it prints it. However if a string has a space in it, my program won't count it as a palindrome (Example: nurses run). What should I be adding to make the program exclude the space, when it's accounting for palindromes?

Palindrome: a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards, e.g. 'madam' or 'nurses run'

```
import sys

strings = []
for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    strings += [s]

def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
        return True
    elif word[0] == word[-1]:
        is_palindrome(word[1:-1])
        return True
    else:
        return False


def printpalindromes(strings):
    for s in strings:
        if is_palindrome(s) == True:
            print(s)

printpalindromes(strings)
```

Comment: If anything, you're not  `return`ing the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye fixed. Can you check the new edit?

Answer (score 1):

Try stripping out the whitespaces before doing the palindrome check

```
>>> x = "nurses run"
>>> x.replace(" ", "")
'nursesrun'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
def palindrome(word):
    if ' ' in word:
       word = word.replace(' ', '')
    palindrome = reversed(word)
    for letter, rev_letter in zip(word, palindrome):
        if letter != rev_letter:
            return 'Not Palindrome'
    return 'Palindrome'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still incorrect in the elif statement. You've added `return True` when you should actually be returning the response from your recursive call as previously mentioned.

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
        return True
    elif word[0] == word[-1]:
        return is_palindrome(word[1:-1])
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution of your problem:

```
import sys

sys.argv = ["    nurses         ", "       run       "]
word = "".join([s.strip() for s in sys.argv])
print("{} {} palindrome".format(word, "is" if word == word[::-1] else "is not"))
```

or you can just create the word out of sys.argv like this:

```
word = "".join(sys.argv).replace(" ","")
```

Comment: There is no need for `[]` in `join()`, it can handle generator expressions just fine. It also conserves memory.